# Dymola .bak-mo files

Tags: version-control, backup, dymola

Dymola generates backup files with extension `*.bak-mo` when deleting a file. Can I turn that off completely and permanently? I use version control, so I do not need that file. When deleting packages, even whole directories are remaining. Can I turn that off also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be turned off via the advanced flag

`Advanced.AutoDeleteDirectories = true;`

which corresponds to this setting in the options dialog:

[image]